# Red-Hat Cluster failover notification?

Tags: redhat, cluster, rhcs

Is there anyway to get a notification / setup a notification mechanizem when the cluster fails over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to config "SNMP TRAPS"

[SNMP traps RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/63108)